# 405 error not allowed -rtorrent -python

Tags: python, xmlrpclib

I'm trying to connect to my seedbox so I can send it torrents.
But I keep getting this

`xmlrpclib.ProtocolError: <ProtocolError for username:password@seedbox.io/RPC2: 405 Not Allowed>`

Here's my code

```
import xmlrpclib
server_url = "http://username:password@.seedbox.io/"

server = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy(server_url)
torrents = server.download_list()
```

Comment: server_url has a fairly bizarre value. Can you access that URL with a browser?

Comment: it's normal i remove the part just before .seedbox.io because it's the same value than my username

Answer (score 1):

Fix your web server config, i.e. allow outside POST requests on /RPC2.

PS: And it's 2018, use https.